# Using my custom External Login with spring boot oauth2 (authorization grant type)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have to implement Oauth2 with spring boot Oauth2 and spring boot security, but I have one problem, I want to authenticate user with my custom external login page and after login success i want to redirect again to authorization endpoint to authorize client for request resources

How I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: please anybody can support me

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom authentication provider.

or implement AuthenticationProvider class and write your authentication logic.

and after that

```
@Configuration
public class YourWebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.authenticationProvider(yourAuthProviderBean);

  }
}
```